# Dynamically going further into a nested list

Tags: python

Hi so I have a tree like nested list that is dynamically expanding. Currently I've been using eval() and exec() to traverse down. Is there a better way to do this? I feel like I shouldn't be doing it the way I currently am.

ex of my code:

```
tree = ["Outer", ["Inner", ["MoreIn", ["InAgain", [] ] ] ] ]
depth = "tree[-1][-1]"

def addToTree(code):
    if eval(depth) != []:
        exec(depth+"[-1]")
    exec(depth+"="code)
```

It works, but this feels really janky. Is there a way to do this cleaner?

Input:

```
code = ["AnotherOne", [ ]]
```

Output:

```
tree = ["Outer", ["Inner", ["MoreIn", ["InAgain", ["AnotherOne", []] ] ] ] ]
depth = "tree[-1][-1][-1][-1][-1][-1]" #or whatever is the next empty []
```

Comment: Yes, there’s a better way. It’s hard to tell what you’re asking, though. Could you provide a “before” and “after” and a complete runnable script, please? (This one seems to be missing commas and values for `Outer`, `Inner`, etc..)

Comment: Tell us what the goal is, what the input looks like in general, and what the output would be, with examples.

Comment: Traversing down you can do in a `while` or `for` loop without resorting to eval and exec. Like `node = tree; for i in itertools.count(0): if node[-1] ==[]: break  else: node=node[-1]` You needn't be at the top level to make the last assignment, `node[-1]=[AnotherOne, []]` should do. You may have other stopping criteria in mind but the principle should be clear.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to achieve? I have a feeling you don't *really* want a string that looks like `"tree[-1][-1][-1][-1][-1][-1]"`, this is just some hacky version of what your actual goal here is.

Comment: @Denziloe Right it's insanely hacky. I just want to be able to find the next empty list and replace it with a list with a string and another like like ["somestring", [ ]]

Comment: Okay -- got you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach avoiding recurrence:

```
import itertools

def nest(flat):
    out = []
    for l in reversed(flat):
        out = [l, out]
    return out

def nest_another(nested, next_):
    last = nested
    for depth in itertools.count(0):
        if last[-1] == []:
            break
        last = last[-1]
    last[-1] = [next_, []]
    return depth, last[-1], nested

items = ["item{}".format(i) for i in range(4)]
nested = nest(items)
print(nested)
depth, last, nested = nest_another(nested, 'another')
print(depth, last, nested)
last[-1] = ['yet_another', []]
print(nested)
```

prints:

```
# ['item0', ['item1', ['item2', ['item3', []]]]]
# 3 ['another', []] ['item0', ['item1', ['item2', ['item3', ['another', []]]]]]
# ['item0', ['item1', ['item2', ['item3', ['another', ['yet_another', []]]]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you're asking, generally, how to loop through an array with lot's of complex inners.  What I would do is use a recursive function. This simply prints out all the elements in the array, but with a little adaption, you can do a lot with it.

```
arr = [[3,2],2,[[5,9],3,4]]

def recursiveLookThrough(arr):
    for element in arr:
        if (isinstance(element,list)):
            recursiveLookThrough(element)
        else:
            print(element)

recursiveLookThrough(arr)
```

Comment: It's a lot cleaner, but wouldn't it have a worst run time than the jank code theoretically since you would have to traverse all the way down every time you want to add to the tree. But since the janky code keeps track of the depth level, it wouldn't be force to retraverse down every time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using exec, you're almost certainly doing it wrong.

Recursion is probably the nicest way to do what you want:

```
def add(tree, string):
    head, body = tree
    if body:
        add(body, string)
    else:
        body[0:2] = string, []

add(tree, "Wow")
print(tree)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is the head variable actually doing anything?

Comment: Good question. Looks like the answer is "no" here. It is best to leave it in though, for clarity. It is being used as a dummy variable in the tuple assignment, if you know what that is. Try typing `head, body = tree` outside of the function and `print(head, body)` to see how it works if you're not familiar.